# How to save a record with multiples foreing keys in Larave 8?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables:

vehicle_brands:

- id
- name

engines:

- id
- name

vehicles:

- id
- name
- vehicle_brand_id
- engine_id

**vehicles** depends of vehicle_brands and engines, I want save vehicle_brands and engines id when I save a vehicle record, I would do this but I think this isn't the best approach

```
$vehicleBrand = VehicleBrand::find(1);

$engine = Engine::find(1);

$vehicle = Vehicle::create[(...)];

$vehicleBrand->vehicles()->save($vehicles);

$engine->vehicles()->save($vehicles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set it directly during creation:

```php
$vehicle = Vehicle::create([
   "vehicle_brand_id" => 1,
   "engine_id" => 1
]);
```

No need to look up your brand and engine of you already know the IDs. Make sure the values above are marked as `$fillable`

Comment: I am trying to eliminate technical debt, so I thought there should be an easier and better way to do that.